# JSF application: Open file, not download it

Tags: java, jsf-2

**Current situation:** I'm trying to create a `JSF app` (portlet) which should contains links to excel files (`xls`, `xlt`) stored on public network drive `G:` mapped for all users in our company. The main goal is to unify access to these files and save work to users in search of the reports somewhere on G drive. I hope it's clear..?

I'm using following servlet to open a file. Problem is, that it's not just opened, but downloaded by browser and after that, opened:

```
@WebServlet(name="fileHandler", urlPatterns={"/fileHandler/*"})
public class FileServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
  private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240; // 10KB.
  private String filePath;

  public void init() throws ServletException  {
    this.filePath = "c:\\Export";
    System.out.println("fileServlet initialized: " + this.filePath);
  }

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  {
    String requestedFile = request.getPathInfo();
    File file = new File(filePath, URLDecoder.decode(requestedFile, "UTF-8"));
    String contentType = getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName());

    response.reset();
    response.setBufferSize(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"");

    BufferedInputStream input = null;
    BufferedOutputStream output = null;

    try {
      input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);
      output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
      int length;

      while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
      }
    } finally { 
      close(output);
      close(input);
    }
  }

  private static void close(Closeable resource) {
    if (resource != null) resource.close();
  }
}
```

How to just start appropriate application (e.g. `Excel`, `Word`, etc.) clicking on link (with absolute file path) and open the file in its original location?

**UPDATE:** I'm trying to use `<a>` tag:

```
<a href="/G:/file.xls">File</a> // various "/" "\" "\\" combinations
<a href="file:///G:/file.xls">File</a>
```

But it doesn't work:

```
type Status report
message /G:/file.xls
description The requested resource is not available.
```

Comment: You can't open a file on a remote web server just like if it was on your local machine. If the server is your local machine, then use a `file://` URL. Open the file from your browser, copy and paste the URL that is in the address bar, and paste it in the `href` attribute of your link.

Comment: Thanks. It's opened from shared G: drive which is the same for server and also for users in domain. I've tried your suggestion, but I'm not sure how.. This path works `file:///G:/test.pdf` in a browser, but not this: `<a href="file:///G:/test.pdf">file</a>`

Comment: It works from `html` file, but not from the JSF application :(

Comment: That's due to a security restriction in the browser. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme (end of the page).

Comment: Aha, you're right. It's working in IE9... so I have to set the chrome and firefox to allow it!  Thank you very much. You can answer my question to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File URLs are considered as a security risk by most browsers, because they cause files to be opened on a client's machine by a web page, without the end user being aware of it. If you really want to do that, you'll have to configure the browser to allow it.

See the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) for solutions.